# How do you serve svg and fixtures with Karma Runner (aka Testacular)

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I've been trying for the past two hours to get Karma runner to serve an svg file and an html fixture but so far no luck.

Following the second answer on this thread: [Error while integrating html with testacularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13019215/error-while-integrating-html-with-testacularjs) I've been trying to use `served` to indicate that my fixtures and svg file should be distributed by the server but I'm still getting 'NOT FOUND's

```
files = [
  JASMINE,
  JASMINE_ADAPTER,
  REQUIRE,
  REQUIRE_ADAPTER,

  // put all components in requirejs 'paths' config here (included: false)
  { pattern: 'preview/public/components/**/*.js', included: false },
  { pattern: 'preview/public/js/**/*.js', included: false },

  // assets
  { pattern: 'preview/public/img/svg/*.svg', included: false, served: true },

  // helpers & fixtures for jasmine-jquery
  { pattern: 'test/libs/**/*.js', included: true },
  { pattern: 'test/fixtures/**/*.html', included: false, served: true },

  // all src and test modules (included: false)
  { pattern: 'test/specs/**/*.spec.js', included: false },

  // test main require module last
  'test/test-main.js'
];
```

I'm setting the `jasmine.getFixtures().fixturesPath` to `/fixtures` and I can see that it's using the correct path but I still end up with...

`GET http://localhost:9876/img/svg/directional-pad-gradients.svg 404 (Not Found)`
`GET http://localhost:9876/fixtures/directional-pad.html 404 (Not Found)`

If anyone has an example of loading fixtures and/or svg with Karma runner I would **really** love to take a look. Thank you!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Answering my own question here...

I was trying to load my fixtures at`http://localhost:9876/fixtures/directional-pad.html`

Instead I should have tried accessing them at `http://localhost:9876/base/test/fixtures/directional-pad.html`

Karma stores everything under the `base/` route, so any static file routes you add will need to start with that.

Comment: Since you are using karma with fixtures, could you please help me? -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209749/how-can-i-use-html-fixtures-with-karma-test-runner-using-qunit thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is this only true if you use the `basePath` option in the karma config? I noticed that Karma can also store things in an `absolute/` directory.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is to set-up a proxy server.

A good example of a test system using a proxy server is
https://github.com/yearofmoo-articles/AngularJS-Testing-Article

which is the example from Year of Moo's great testing tutorial.
http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/01/full-spectrum-testing-with-angularjs-and-testacular.html

You set the proxy up in the karma config file

```
proxies = {
  '/': 'http://localhost:8100/'
};
```

Then you need to set-up the server on 8100

this can be done using http-server

> npm install http-server --save-dev

then create two files

#### ./server.sh

```
nf --procfile ./config/Procfile.server start
```

#### ./config/Procfile.server

```
web_server: ./node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server -p 8100 preview/public
```

Then you need to run you server

```
./server.sh
```

Then when you run the tests, the proxy will serve up your files.