# How does one write unit tests in Karma that interact with SVG graphics using Snap.svg?

Tags: javascript, svg, karma-runner, snap.svg, karma-mocha

I am working on a web app that uses SVG graphics for most of its display and interaction. I would like to use Karma to create unit tests that load an SVG asset, makes sure that certain groups/paths are present, etc.

I haven't found any straightforward answers to how to do this yet, or figured it out on my own yet. I am attempting to get a simple test like this to pass (using mocha & chai):

```
describe("SimpleDecalRoulette", function() {
      it("decal SVG can be loaded", function() {
        var decalLoaded = false;    
        var SVG = Snap.load("/base/app/img/decal.svg", function(fragment) {
          decalLoaded = true;
        });
        expect(decalLoaded).to.be.true;
      });
    });
```

Initially, I assumed that including the svg file in the "files" directive of karma.conf.js would suffice:

```
files: [
  { pattern: 'app/bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.min.js', watched: false, included: true, served: true },
  { pattern: 'app/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', watched: false, included: true, served: true },
  { pattern: 'app/bower_components/snap.svg/dist/snap.svg-min.js', watched: false, included: true, served: true },
  { pattern: 'app/js/\*\*/\*.js', watched: true, included: true, served: true },
  { pattern: 'app/img/decal.svg', watched: true, included: false, served: true },
  { pattern: 'app/img/assets.svg', watched: true, included: false, served: true },
  'tests/\*\*/\*_spec.js'
],
proxies: {
  '/app/img/': '/base/app/img/'
}
```

However, attempting to load the svg files from `app/img/decal.svg` or `base/app/img/decal.svg` both resulted in 404 errors. I have also tried using the 'proxies' directive, as detailed in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938580/how-do-you-serve-svg-and-fixtures-with-karma-runner-aka-testacular), but haven't gotten that to work yet either (as seen above).

Is this something that karma can do or is this a use case that should be handled differently? I need to load and interact with SVGs for karma to be useful in writing unit tests for this game.

Comment: Thx for this. finally able to rid myself of *.svg warnings.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing this exact same thing and have just got it working.

My `karma.conf.js` includes the svg files in the `files` array:

`{ pattern: 'src/svg/*.svg', included: false, served: true }`

and in the test I can load this as:

`Snap.load('base/src/svg/Drawing.svg',...)`;

The main difference in my test is the way that I use a deferred to make sure the SVG is loaded before I do any assertions. I'm using Jasmine 2.0 which allows for a `done` callback within the `it` function.

```
it('Should load the SVG', function(done) {
   Snap.load('base/src/svg/Drawing.svg', function (fragment) {
     expect(...).toBe(...);
     done();
   });
});
```

You can read more about Async Support here: http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support

and for version 1.3: http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction.html#section-Asynchronous_Support